# cp command "loud" version

Tags: command-line, cp

Is there any way, to make cp - command "loud"?

Sometimes I want copy large file, or directory with many files. It is very useful, to see what cp is doing right now, which file, % of this file or % of all copy procedure. When I apt-get something, I got information about every package it is downloading, unpacking, installing... I can turn it off with -q (quiet) flag. Is there any way to make opposite thing to cp? I can't find it on man page.

Comment: you can use `rsync -Pa` instead of `cp`.

Comment: Hmm, I guess it can work, but I was looking for the simplest version of answer. I don't know how rsync work, what is actually difference between this and cp, what new flags i need to learn. I guess your answer is better (because I don't need to install anything new) but other one is simpler.

Comment: `rsync` is a fast and versatile file-copying tool which can copy locally and to/from a remote host. It offers many options to control its behavior,and its remote-update protocol can minimize network traffic to make transferring updates between machines fast and efficient.It is widely used for backups and mirroring and as an improved copy command for everyday use. use `man rsync` for more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**gcp** is an advanced command line file copier that is inspired by the standard cp command but provides various advanced features like progress bar indicator, source lists, continuous copying even if there is a problematic file etc.

just install and use: `sudo apt-get install gcp`
Here is a complete list of options : `gcp --help`

```
Usage: 
        gcp [options] FILE DEST
        gcp [options] FILE1 [FILE2 ...] DEST-DIR

        gcp --help for options list


Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -r, --recursive       copy directories recursively
  -f, --force           force overwriting of existing files
  --preserve=PRESERVE   preserve  the  specified  attributes
  -L, --dereference     always follow symbolic links in sources
  -P, --no-dereference  never follow symbolic links in sources
  --no-fs-fix           don't fix filesystem name incompatibily
  --no-progress         deactivate progress bar
  -v, --verbose         Show what is currently done

  sources saving:
    --sources-save=SOURCES_SAVE
                        Save source arguments
    --sources-replace=SOURCES_REPLACE
                        Save source arguments and replace memory if it already
                        exists
    --sources-load=SOURCES_LOAD
                        Load source arguments
    --sources-del=SOURCES_DEL
                        delete saved sources
    --sources-list      List names of saved sources
    --sources-full-list
                        List names of saved sources and files in it
```

ref: http://mylinuxbook.com/gcp-advanced-command-line-file-copier-inspired-by-cp/

Comment: Yes, it worked perfect! And, what it's also important for me, command is almost "the same", don't need to learn/remember anything new.